# How would you declare the parameter type in the following cases

Tags: c++

I was asked the following question:

**How would you declare the parameter type in the following cases**

1. — T is a simple type (e.g. int) and is used as an "in" parameter.
2. — T is a complicated type, and parameter is used as an "in"
   parameter.
3. — T is a simple type and is used as an "out" parameter.

I supposed that in the first case we can simply pass it by value since the performance penalty is not so much, in the second case we should pass it as a reference since it is a more complicated type, and in the third case we should pass it by reference since it is an out parameter. Am I right? **Is there any reason to not use reference in all the cases?** From the question I can not understand if "in parameter" means that this would not change inside the function so we can pass it as const.

Comment: When they ask you a question, you can always ask for clarifications. Anyway, I think an _"in"_ or "input" parameter is a parameter that is "observed" by the function, but _not_ modified.

Answer (score 0):

> — T is a simple type (e.g. int) and is used as an "in" parameter.

In this case, I'd just pass T (e.g. int) *by value*.

> — T is a complicated type, and parameter is used as an "in" parameter.

In this case, I'd pass T using *reference to const*: `const T&` (to avoid e.g. useless and potentially expensive deep-copies).

> — T is a simple type and is used as an "out" parameter.

In this case, I'd pass *by reference (non-const)*: `T&`. This allows modifications done to the parameter value inside the function body to be "visible" outside of the function body, at the call site (think e.g. of a swapping function, that could have a prototype like `void swap(T& x, T& y);`).

Comment: so by saying "in parameter" we mean that the parameter would not change inside the function (and we can use const) ?